# How do I write a SQL query to display course_id, course_name and fee collected from each course?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, relational-database

The various tables and their columns are:

1)Course

```
course_id
course_name
duration
fee
```

2)Registration

```
course_id
stud_id
doj
```

3)Student

```
stud_id
first_name
last name
city
dob
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT 
    C.COURSE_ID,
    C. COURSE_NAME, 
    COUNT(R.COURSE_ID) * FEES AS TOTAL_FEES 
FROM 
    COURSE C, 
    REGISTRATION R, 
WHERE 
    C.COURSE_ID = R.COURSE_ID 
GROUP BY 
    R.COURSE_ID
```

Comment: this smells like a homework question. -- for the record, every non aggregated field in your query needs to be explicitly stated in the Group By statement even if it won't have an impact. So your query won't even run as is.

Comment: I need fee collected for each course. There are many registrations for a single course. For Example a course named xyz whose fee is 5000 and for which 8 students have registered for course xyz. so i need 8*5000 as the answer as total_fee for course xyz

Comment: then you should have mentioned that in your question. It is important to include the relation between tables. one to one, one to many, primary keys.....etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.cource_id, c.course_name, (totalNumberOfStudentPerCourse.totalNumberOfStudent * c.fee) as totalFee
FROM Course c
INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT r.course_id, COUNT(r.stud_id) as totalNumberOfStudent
        FROM Registration r
        GROUP BY r.course_id) totalNumberOfStudentPerCourse ON c.course_id =  totalNumberOfStudentPerCourse.course_id
```

the subquery creates a totalNumberOfStudentPerCourse table that looks like this:

```
course_id     totalNumberOfStudent
1             4
2             2
```

**example:**

course:

```
course_id  course_name  fee

1           math         300
2           english      200
```

registration:

```
course_id    stud_id
1             1
1               2
1               3
1               4
2               5
2               6
```

result:

```
course_id   course_name     totalFee
1           math            1200
2           english         400
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a select on your `group by` query and then join it with the `course` table to use the rest of its fields.

```
SELECT aa.course_id, aa.course_name, aa.fee * _aa.total_registrations AS total_fees
FROM course AS aa
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT course_id, COUNT(*) as total_registrations
    FROM registration
    GROUP BY course_id
) AS _aa
ON aa.course_id = _aa.course_id
ORDER BY aa.course_name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
             c.course_id
           , c.course_name
           , SUM(c.fee) AS TOTALFEES

    FROM Course c
    JOIN Registration r 
                       ON c.course_id = r.course_id

    GROUP BY 
              c.course_id
            , c.course_name

    HAVING TOTALFEES > 15000
    ORDER BY c.course_id ASC;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    select c.courseid, c.coursename, c.fees * aa.tr as TOTALFEES
    from course c 
    LEFT JOIN (
          select courseid,COUNT(*) as tr
          from registration 
          group by courseid
    ) aa
    ON c.courseid = aa.courseid
    order by c.courseid;
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer?

Comment: This has trivial changes from another answer from years earlier.

Answer (score -1):

```
select courseid,coursename,(tsp_course.totalstd * c.fees) as TOTALFEES
 from course c 
 inner join(select r.courseid,count(r.courseid) as totalstd
            from registration r
            group by r.courseid) tsp_course using(courseid)
 order by courseid;
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

`select c.courseid,c.coursename,(totalpercourse.totalstudent*c.fees) from course c inner join (select courseid,count(studid) as totalstudent from registration group by courseid) totalpercourse on c.courseid=totalpercourse.courseid where (totalpercourse.totalstudent*c.fees)>15000 order by courseid asc;`

Comment: Congratulations with your first answer on StackOverflow!

Please [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/17695211) the code in your answer to make it readable.

Code-only answers are discouraged. Therefore please also add a short explanation of how your code relates the the question.

Answer (score -2):

This is what you are looking for:

```
Select course.course_id,course.course_name,(count(reg.stud_id)*course.fee)  
From Course course INNER JOIN Registration reg  
ON course.course_id=reg.course_id  
GROUP BY  course.course_id,course.course_name,course.fee
```

Comment: Do add a line at the last if needed     order by course.course_name ;